# How can I find free British RP articulatory phonetics images?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, listening, phonetics

I need some free images of British RP articulatory phonetics (for 44 sounds) like the following one.

However, I can collect them from youtube video tutorials by taking snapshots. But the problem is copyright. I'm afraid of copyright problems. Is it a problem if I take them from video tutorials and use them in my youtube videos? Or, how can I find that kind of image for free?
[image]